# There is no underscore in the angular-material input field

Tags: angular, angular-material

On the input form I use
@angular/material 13.2.5

Here is the code

```
<mat-dialog-content>
  <p mat-dialog-title>{{dialogTitle}}</p>
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input
      #inputTitle
      matInput maxlength="100"
      [(ngModel)]="quizDto.name"
      (keydown.enter)="confirm()"
    />
    <button
      *ngIf="quizDto.name.trim().length > 0"
      class="clear-icon"
      mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
      (click)="quizDto.name= ''"
    >
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

But when I launch the application, the input field looks like this:

[image: main]

the picture shows that there is no underscore in the input field.
But if you open the usage examples on the site
[https://material.angulal](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)
Then exactly the same code displays the input element with an underscore

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Standard form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: angulal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have added Material CSS in your `style.scss`.

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Also make sure you have imported Material Form Field Module in your NgModule.

```
import {MatInputModule,MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';

// ....
imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ...
],
```